# how to set values from table in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I'm working on displaying currency list from table in dropdown in laravel blade.
In the dropdown option i want to set first value currency as set in csv file.
but dropdown records are from table.

how do i set first value in dropdown as set in uploaded csv file.

Thanks for your help.

following are my code.

my.blade.php

storing currency from csv in `variable = $array['currency']`

```
<td class="currency"style="width: 10%;">  
    {{ Form::select('currency',$currencies , "",['class'=>"form-control   select-currency",'data-plugin'=>"select2",
    ]) }}
 </td>
```

MyModel.php

```
$currencies = Currency::all()->pluck('code', 'id');
 $questions_table = \View::make('confirmation.form_questionnaire',
['questions' => $record['questions'], 'response_type' =>$record['response_type'], 'currencies' => $currencies]);
```

[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9xKo.png)

Comment: You mean the first part of the drop-down need to come from CSV and secound part is from the Currency ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, not exactly in dropdown all the data (currency list) will be displayed from TABLE values, but the first value will be displayed as set in CSV file.

Comment: eg. in csv file in currency =   USD then in dropdown =  USD value will be display first then all other currency value.

Comment: the value USD is also in the table? Or both table and csv have different values?

Comment: yes USD is also in table, no the table and csv have same values.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Order by CSV filed Currency code

```
$csvFiled = 'USD';
$currencies = Currency::orderByRaw("FIELD(code , '$csvFiled') DESC")->pluck('code', 'id');
```

**OR**

Very first get the list in the array

```
$currencies = Currency::pluck('code', 'id')->toArray();
```

then find the CSV record and set as the first index

```
$csvValuekey = array_search('USD', $currencies); // $key = 2;
unset($users[$csvValuekey]); // Remove from main array 
$fOption = [$csvValuekey => 'USD'];
$finallList = array_merge($fOption,$currencies); // Merge and set on top
```

Now add the `$finallList` in form select

Comment: the records will come from table, and the currency set in csv file will match with table record and set to first

Comment: Yes I understand, $csvFiled set your csv field at here and then run the codes
otherwise set the $csvFiled as as static let say as 'USD' then print the result of $currencies

Comment: {{ $selected_currency = \App\Models\Currency::orderByRaw("FIELD('code' , $array['currency']) DESC")->pluck('code', 'id')}}

Comment: echo the value of $array['currency'] and paste in comment
OR add $csvFiled = $array['currency'];
rest is same

Comment: ohh sorry, my mistake got it, i was passing with string $array['currency'] that's why it was giving me an error

Comment: I will suggest you to print it like this: echo '<pre>';print_r($currencies->toArray());exit;

Comment: in this $csvValuekey = array_search('USD', $users), $users is empty array object or what?

Comment: I think you didn't check the answer you need to go with first option

Comment: Ohhh and the users is currencies that is by mistake: Updated

Comment: <?php
                            $val = $array['currency'];
                        ?>
                        {{ Form::select('currency',\App\Models\Currency::orderByRaw("FIELD(code , '$val') DESC")->pluck('code', 'id'),
                            "",['class'=>"form-control select-currency",
                            'data-plugin'=>"select2"]) }}

Comment: above lines work for me, @DsRaj Thanks for your time and help

Comment: you are running query on in blade file?

Comment: will there be problem? running queries in blade file. since i'm new to laravel

Comment: This is not good way,
add the query in model and get the data from there via controller and pass the variable/array/object to view and use it

Comment: my.blade.php    
                        {{ Form::select('currency', $currencies,
                             $array['currency'], ['class'=>"form-control select-currency",
                            'data-plugin'=>"select2"]) }}

Comment: MyModel.php  $currencies = Currency::pluck('code', 'id')->toarray(); return view('my.blade.php', $currencies)

Comment: Add the code in the model in a function call the function from controller and get value